# Php can't get the right infos of MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

My Php code on my ubuntu webmin mysql server:

```
$reqdiasserver = "SELECT * from user_data WHERE `googleID` like 1234;"; 
$userdias = mysqli_query($conn ,$reqdiasserver); 
$somanydias = mysqli_fetch_array($userdias , MYSQL_ASSOC); 

echo '<pre>'; print_r($reqdiasserver); print_r($userdias); print_r($somanydias); 
echo "NAME: " . $somanydias["name"];
```

Gives this result:

```
SELECT * from user_data WHERE `googleID` like 1234;mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 38
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
NAME: 0
```

But the name at googleID '1234' is 'emanuel' and not 0

the structure of googleID in the db is text because gID's are too long I think for integers

why does it result 0 ?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE`; why aren't you using `=`?

Comment: try `\`googleID\` = 1234;`

Comment: tried, same output

Comment: what is type of `googleID` ? `varchar` or `integer`

Comment: try "like '1234'", i.e. you are using a wrong type in select

Comment: remove `;` after 1234, `$reqdiasserver = "SELECT * from user_data WHERE googleID = 1234";`

Comment: googleID is text because gID's are too long I think for integers @MudassarSaiyed

Comment: Niklesh is right check the filed type of googleID...in integer than =1234 and if varchar than ='1234'

Comment: It always is a good idea to use specific column names instead of the star operator in SELECT queries. I suspect there is no column with name `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line:

```
$somanydias = mysqli_fetch_array($userdias , MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

should be as:

```
$somanydias = mysqli_fetch_array($userdias , MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//                                    notice this ^
```

Comment: Indeed, well spotted!

Comment: I searched 2 days on this problem. Take 10000 Thanks and 15 rep